# Xamarin Iphone / Android pass by reference

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin to develop ios and android apps on one platefrom, c# is the language used.

I have a design that mimics the one below. A manager class that handles operations done to a collection, a Model class that groups data, and a View that displays the models it gets from the manager. I am displaying the models in a table, the view below is how I am doing so on iOS.

The view subscribes to any changes done to the collection in the manager and triggers a view update whenever one occurs. The model is responsible for removing itself from the collection if it is no longer used after a certain amount of time, thus I pass a reference to the list when the model is created.

This pattern is working on android devices but doesn't seem to work when ran on iOS. I've traced the problem to the removeDevice in the model class but can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. My guess if a pass by reference / value problem but I am not sure. Is there something obvious I am missing or do I need to use a different pattern for iOS?

**New Information**
After experimenting more this seems relevant. The iOS table is in a tab view and not the initial tab which means ViewController is not initialized until the tab is clicked. I found that if I didn't click the tab it would remove the Models from the list. Something else interesting is if I removed the CollectionChanged subscription it would as well.

```
public partial class ViewController: UIViewController
{
  private List<Model> itemList;
  private BlueTooth ble;
  private UITableView deviceTable;

  public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
      ble = BlueTooth.Instance;
    }

  public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
      manager = ble.getManager();
      itemList = manager.modelList.ToList();
      manager.modelList.CollectionChanged += UpdateView;

      deviceTable = new UITableView
      {
        Source = new DeviceTableSource(itemList)
      };
      View.AddSubview(deviceTable);
    }

    void UpdateView(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      itemList = ble.getManager().ModelList.ToList();
      deviceTable.Source = new DeviceTableSource(itemList);
      deviceTable.ReloadData();
     }
}
```

Manager Class

```
class Manager{
   public ObservableCollection<Model> modelList {get; set;}

   public Manager(){
     modelList= new ObervableCollection<Model>();
   }

  public addModel(){
   Create a Model object with reference to ModelList
   Add Model to ModelList
  }

  public updateModel(){
    update Model in List
  }
}
```

Model Class

```
class Model{
   private ObservableCollection<Model> list;
   private Timer removeTimer;

   Model(modelList){
     removeTimer += onTimedEvent
   }

   OnTimedEvent(){
     removeDevice();
   }

   removeDevice(){
     modelList.remove(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, if you didn't click the tab or disuse CollectionChanged subscription, there will be nothing in `ModelList`?

Comment: Case 1: I don't comment out CollectionChanged. Adds new models to the Modellist only has a problem removing if I switch tabs.  
Case 2: I comment out CollectionChanged. Adds and removes models correctly in either tab but no notification is sent to the view that the data has updated.